# Notifications of a new answers and comments on a question that is not mine?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Is it possible to get notifications of new comments or questions concernaning a question that is not necessary mine ? is this functionnality already been discussed here in Meta SSE ??

Comment: If you found an answer to your question, then put it as an answer, don't edit it in you the question.

Comment: okey you are right

Answer (score 3):

I found a this extension [StackEye](https://stackapps.com/questions/4454/stackeye-chrome-extension-to-follow-users-and-questions-on-stackexchange-sites), it answers my question.

**StackEye** is a Chrome extension which can be used to follow other users for their answers and questions. Using StackEye you can also add a question to your watchlist there by getting notifications for each answer/comment on it.

Comment: Is there a non-extension solution as well? Actually this can be done in any forum software. Would be nice if stackoverflow provides it too...